# AttributeError:'Tensor' object has no attribute '_keras_history'

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras, deep-learning

```
Aux_input = Input(shape=(wrd_temp.shape[1],1), dtype='float32')#shape (,200)
Main_input = Input(shape=(wrdvec.shape[1],),dtype='float32')#shape(,367)

X = Bidirectional(LSTM(20,return_sequences=True))(Aux_input)
X = Dropout(0.2)(X)
X = Bidirectional(LSTM(28,return_sequences=True))(X)
X = Dropout(0.2)(X)
X = Bidirectional(LSTM(28,return_sequences=False))(X)
Aux_Output = Dense(Opt_train.shape[1], activation= 'softmax' )(X)#total 22 classes

x = keras.layers.concatenate([Main_input,Aux_Output],axis=1)

x = tf.reshape(x,[1,389,1])#here 389 is the shape of the new input i.e.(
Main_input+Aux_Output)

x = Bidirectional(LSTM(20,return_sequences=True))(x)
x = Dropout(0.2)(x)
x = Bidirectional(LSTM(28,return_sequences=True))(x)
x = Dropout(0.2)(x)
x = Bidirectional(LSTM(28,return_sequences=False))(x)
Main_Output = Dense(Opt_train.shape[1], activation= 'softmax' )(x)

model = Model(inputs=[Aux_input,Main_input], outputs=    [Aux_Output,Main_Output])
```

Error occurs in line declaring the model i.e. model = Model(), here the attribute error has occurred, Also if there is any other mistake in my implementation please do take a not and notify me in the comment section.

Comment: Try `x = Reshape((1,389,1))(x)`

Comment: Would this work as x is a tensor

Comment: `x` is a `keras` tensor.

Comment: Shape must be rank 3 but is rank 2 for 'bidirectional_4/Tile' (op: 'Tile') with input shapes: [?,1,1], [2]., any help with this @Marcin Mozejko (Error occured after I made amendments as you recommended) ?

Comment: could you print out `model.summary()`?

Comment: x = Bidirectional(LSTM(20,return_sequences=True))(x)
Error occurs in this line hence cannot print model summary

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148873/discussion-between-karan-patel-and-marcin-mozejko).

Comment: Yes... I also think you should replace `tf.reshape` with `x = Reshape((1,389,1))(x)`

Comment: @Marcin Mozejko Thank you for drawing my attention towards the Keras function for reshaping used it in a different way but it worked.

Comment: @daniel 13 yea I implemented it

Comment: So may I formulate an answer?

Comment: I would appreciate if you accept and upvote my answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem lied in the fact that using every `tf` operation should be encapsulated by either:

1. Using `keras.backend` functions,
2. `Lambda` layers,
3. Designated `keras` functions with the same behavior.

When you are using `tf` operation - you are getting `tf` tensor object which doesn't have `history` field. When you use `keras` functions you will get `keras.tensor`s.